# Using Subversion and TortoiseSVN, how do you clear your local action history?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

1. I merge changes of a file from a branch into the trunk-branch.
2. I wrongly resolved a conflict, and want to start from scratch, so I revert the trunk-file to it's original state.
3. I redo step 1, but nothing happens. In the merge window, I check the log, all branches I want to merge into this file are grayed out. This is TortoiseSVN's way of telling me "You already merged these changes into this file, no need to do it a 2nd time."

Since nothing was comitted, this has to be client-side issue. I tried a cleanup, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, the merge information is kept in the parent directory's property svn:mergeinfo. In Windows XP you can access this using the directory's context menu -> Properties -> Subversion. I only reverted the file, so TortoiseSVN did not clear this info.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should mark the file as conflict resolved. If it doesn't help or you are not available to do this, try to remove the sorces and checkout them back from svn.

Comment: There's no conflict to resolve, since I reverted the file. Already tried removing the file and checking it out again, didn't work either. I try to avoid removing the directory, since other files already have a bunch of changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can review uncommitted local changes with the "Check for modifications" menu option and you can discard them with the "Revert" one. Actually, port information is stored as a bunch of regular `svn:mergeinfo` properties and that's what Subversion uses to decide whether a revision has been merged or not.